# Need help to parallelize a loop in python

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have a huge data set and I have to compute for every point of it a series of properties. My code is really slow and I would like to make it faster parallelizing somehow the do loop. I would like each processor to compute the "series of properties" for a limited subsample of my data and then join all the properties together in one array.
I'll try explain what I have to do with an example.

Let's say that my data set is the array `x`:

```
x = linspace(0,20,10000)
```

The "property" I want to get is, for instance, the square root of `x`:

```
prop=[]
for i in arange(0,len(x)):
    prop.append(sqrt(x[i]))
```

The question is how can I parallelize the above loop? Let's assume I have 4 processor and I would like each of them to compute the sqrt of 10000/4=2500 points.

I tried looking at some python modules like `multiprocessing` and `mpi4py` but from the guides I couldn't find the answer to such a simple question.

**EDITS**

I'll thank you all for the precious comments and links you provided me. However, I would like to clarify my question. I'm not interested in the `sqrt` function whatsoever.
I am doing a series of operations within a loop. I perfectly know loops are bad and vectorial operation are always preferable to them but in this case I really have to do a loop. I won't go into the details of my problem because this would add an unnecessary complication to this question.
I would like to split my loop so that each processor does a part of it, meaning that I could run my code 40 times with 1/40 of the loop each and the merger the result but this would be stupid.
This is a brief example

```
     for i in arange(0,len(x)):
         # do some complicated stuff
```

What I want is use 40 cpus to do this:

```
    for npcu in arange(0,40):
       for i in arange(len(x)/40*ncpu,len(x)/40*(ncpu+1)):
          # do some complicated stuff
```

Is that possible or not with python?

Comment: For this particular example, you would get a far better speedup than a mere factor of 4 by usiing `numpy.sqrt(x)` instead of the Python loop.  This might very well also be the case for your real task.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my real task is way more complicated than performing a sqrt. I was just wondering why I couldn't find any example of simple python for loop parallelized.

Comment: In my experience, vectorising is the way to speed up numerical Python loops in 99 percent of the cases, even if they are more complicated.  Describe your real function, and I can probably tell you how to vectorise it.

Comment: I am using vector operations. I have a huge data set (N>1e6 points) and for any point I have to perform 10/20 vectorial operations. This would take slightly 1 seconds for every data point, so in total I end up with 1e6 seconds of computational time, which is not really feasible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is the way that you should do things as I'd expect numpy to have a much more efficient method of going about it, but do you just mean something like this?

```
import numpy
import multiprocessing

x = numpy.linspace(0,20,10000)
p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)

print p.map(numpy.sqrt, x)
```

Here are the results of `timeit` on both solutions.  As @SvenMarcach points out, however, with a more expensive function multiprocessing will start to be much more effective.

```
% python -m timeit -s 'import numpy; x=numpy.linspace(0,20,10000)' 'prop=[]                                                                          
for i in numpy.arange(0,len(x)):
         prop.append(numpy.sqrt(x[i]))'
10 loops, best of 3: 31.3 msec per loop

% python -m timeit -s 'import numpy, multiprocessing; x=numpy.linspace(0,20,10000)
p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)' 'l = p.map(numpy.sqrt, x)' 
10 loops, best of 3: 102 msec per loop
```

At Sven's request, here is the result of `l = numpy.sqrt(x)` which is *significantly* faster than either of the alternatives.

```
% python -m timeit -s 'import numpy; x=numpy.linspace(0,20,10000)' 'l = numpy.sqrt(x)'
10000 loops, best of 3: 70.3 usec per loop
```

Comment: The `multiprocessing` approach is slower because the function executed for each iteration is rather trivial.  if you have a "fat" function in each iteration, you will actually see a speed-up.  It would also be interesting to include `l = numpy.sqrt(x)` in the timimngs.

Comment: @SvenMarnach that is a good point, the only time that I have used `multiprocessing` a lot is for tasks like fetch many webpages, where it was very obviously much much faster.  I hadn't considered that sqrt is in fact a quite trivial function, and I've tried to edit my post to reflect that, as well as to add the results of `numpy.sqrt(x)`.

Comment: Note that the last solution is actually by a factor of 450 faster than the plain Python loop.  It is *not* in between the two other ones!  Which, again, is exactly the point of my above comments.

Comment: @SvenMarnach and now I feel like an idiot(turns out I should pay more attention to msec vs usec D:).  Thank you so much for pointing that out, I was shocked that it was "slower".  Seems like a pretty good case for your original argument.

Answer (score 3):

Parallelizing is not trivial, however you might find [numexpr](https://code.google.com/p/numexpr/) useful.

**For numerical work**, you really should look into the utilities numpy gives you ([vectorize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) and similar), these give you usually a good speedup as a basis to work on.

**For more complicated, non-numerical cases**, you may use `multiprocessing` (see comments).

---

On a sidenote, multithreading is even more non-trivial with python than with other languages, is that CPython has the [Global Interpreter Lock (GIL)](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) which disallows two sections of python code to run in the same interpreter at the same time (i.e. there is no real multithreaded pure python code). For I/O and heavy calculations, third party libraries however tend to release that lock, so that limited multithreading is possible.

This adds to the usual multithreading nuisances of having to mutex shared data accesses and similar.

Comment: Thank for the link. But I was hoping to find a link of the simplest example of a parallelized loop in python.

Comment: @Matteo: Here you go: http://docs.python.org//library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers

Comment: thanks, but from that example, it's not very clear (at least not clear to me) how I can split the task among each processor.

Comment: @Matteo: `Pool.map()` does this automatically.  Just read the documentation.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Thanks, didn't even know that. Maybe you should post that as an alternative answer with more description? Credits definetly go to you for that one.

Comment: Any reason you prefer the low-level `fork()` and `scketpair()` over the nice `multiprocessig` interface?  And I don't think the comments on the GIL are really appropriate here – the OP uses NumPy vectorised operations on vectors with a million entries.  NumPy does release the GIL, so threading would actually be able to speed up this code.  However, I'd prefer separate processes in this case even in languages that don't have a GIL for this kind of application.

Comment: @JonasWielicki: No, I don't post this as an answer since I don't think it's the best approach.  See my comments to the question above.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I think it's more flexible although I really have not looked much into `multiprocessing` yet. And of course, one can easily extend the code to spread across multiple machines using sockets.

Comment: Multiprocessing supports remote managers: http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-remote-manager , its kind of odd to argue against it when you say you havent looked into it before.

Comment: @JonasWielicki: Spreading across multiple machines is indeed a relevant point.  If this is what I'm planning, I usually use the [parallel computing facilities of IPython](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/parallel/index.html).

Comment: @jdi you're right then; I thought I got most of the relevant information when skimming the doc page, but that was some time ago. I edited and you convinced me, thanks.

Comment: @jdi okay, on the other hand, using raw sockets removes the overhead of pickling and unpickling if you have more or less simple data structures, but that's just on a sidenote and only if you really need to optimize.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you take a look at cython:
http://www.cython.org/

It enables you to create c extension for python really quickly, and integrates very well with numpy. Here is a nice tutorial which may help you get started: http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/numpy.html