# Creating parallel for loop in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I looked at similar questions especially [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11211181/10270160) answer. My situation is bit different, so asking question.

```
import os
import multiprocessing as mp

def fun1(str1):
 #function def

if __name__ == '__main__':


    pl1 = mp.Pool(processes=2)
    pl2 = mp.Pool(processes=2)

for (d1,d2,d3) in os.walk('dirname'):
    for d4 in d2:
        pl1.map(fun1,d4)

    for d5 in d3:
        pl2 .map(fun1,d5)
#
```

I am getting file and directory names as strings and passing it to `fun1()`. But the ptoblem is that if I use `pl1.map(fun1,d4)`, it looks like python separates each string character and passes individual character to `fun1()`. I want entire strings `d4,d5` to be passed to `fun1()` and that in parallel to reduce the run time. I created 2 pools `pl1,pl2` so that they can be use separately within the top level `for` loop without causing any problems.

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Careful, if you declare pl1 and pl2 inside the conditional but you loop outside it you might run into problems if you import the file, since the conditional part will not be executed

Comment: Thanks, they are not declared within condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [multiprocessing doc](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) for Pool.map method:

> This method chops the iterable into a number of chunks which it submits to the process pool as separate tasks.

So it takes the string d4 as iterable and send it to processes by letters (one by one). You are probably looking for Pool.apply_async:

```
pl1.apply_async(fun1, d4)
```

Or simply pass *d2* to pool (not using the for cycle "*for d4 in d2*"):

```
pl1.map(fun1, d2)
```

Edit - the final code might lok like this:

```
for (d1,d2,d3) in os.walk('dirname'):
    pl1.map(fun1,d2)
    pl2.map(fun1,d3)
```

Comment: Will `apply_async` take advantage of the pool of `n` processes? Using multiple process is the objective.

Comment: Use the second option I suggested - remove for cycle and use `map(fun1,d2)`... But yes, `apply_async` in a for cycle would run `fun1` in the pool processes the same way the `map` does. In other words, `map` is just a short version of a simple `for` cycle. **NOTE:** you probably want to use `map_async`, because the simple `map` would wait until the first block (**d2**) is done and only after that the second thread pool would launch (**d3**). With `map_async`, both thread pools should start nearly the same time and dont wait until one is completed.

Answer (score 0):

By my understanding, the multiprocessing module is optimized through its use of C behind the scenes. So working with `ctypes` might be the solution to your problem:

```
from ctypes import c_char_p
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager, Value, Pool

manager = Manager()
pool = Pool(processes=2)
pool2 = Pool(processes=2)
for (d1,d2,d3) in os.walk('dirname'):
    for d4 in d2:
        d4_string = manager.Value(c_char_p, d4)
        pool.map(fun1, d4_string)
        pool.join()

    for d5 in d3:
        d4_string = manager.Value(c_char_p, d4)
        pool2.map(fun1, d4_string)
        pool2.join()
```

Comment: How to create pool of processes?